# Fileopenpicker throw exception

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am trying to access file with FileOpenPicker so that i can create with it a storagefile.  But this instruction FileOpenPicker file= new FileOpenPicker() throw an exception. I looked in the official site they talked about checking whether the app is snapped but I didn't understand how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The `FileOpenPicker` class is only supported on Windows Phone 8.1 (if you try to use it on Windows Phone 8.0, you'll get a `System.NotSupportedException`)